# How to ignore hash in URL on Backbone.history.start

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have an URL like mysite.com/en/bla-bla/bla/page#someid
Browser should scrolling window to some page location if find someid in hash URL.

Additionally, I have backbone on page, if user opens page with some hash value in URL backbone failed to *If no defined route matches the current URL*. Backbone can't  match #someid as a path.

```
var result = Backbone.history.start();
        if (!result) {
            console.log("If no defined route matches the current URL");
        }
```

How to solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a catch all [route](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-routes):

> splat parts `*splat`, which can match any number of URL components.

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '*catchall': 'homeRoute',
        // any route defined further down takes precedence on the ones before.
        'real-route/:id': 'realRoute',
    },
    homeRoute: function() { /*...*/ },
    realRoute: function(id) { /*...*/ }
});
```

Define any route you want Backbone to handle, then let any undefined route be caught by the splat.

Comment: thanks Emile, should I write each of possible hash values ?

Comment: You write the routes you want Backbone to take into account. Then, all the other routes are caught by the splat route `*whatever`.